# C# sender problems

Tags: c#

I have 4 buttons and I have linked everyone to the same method in the code.

Now i wanna check which button that has been pressed, by using the code:

```
if(sender == button1)
 {
  //something
  }
```

It seems like sender gives the **text** of the button that has been pressed, i would like the sender to give the **name** of the button!

Thanks!

Comment: Is this about WinForms or WPF? Can you please tag appropriately your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you do not have to check the sender of an event handler because it is assumed that your senders have unique meaninga and therefore unique event handlers. If you're tempted to shove all functionality in one event handler it's a bad practice. You will end up with code that is not maintainable.

However, every rule has exceptions, and in some cases it makes sense to reuse an event handler for multiple senders. In this case you can either cast or use is/as operators to identify the sender:

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    //or
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cast to button:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedButton = (Button) sender;
    }
```

You can then test if the button clicked is THE button.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use a if statement:

```
string Name = ((Button)sender).Name;
if(Name == "somename")
{
    //somecode
}
```

Comment: small detail: don't use begin-capitals for local vars.

Answer (score 0):

`sender` is the object that fired the event (in your case, a `Button` object), not the value of a property of the object.  If you really need to write code that checks the `Name` property of a control (which I would advise against for future maintenance reasons...) you will need to cast it like so:

```
switch(((Button)sender).Name)
{
    case "whatever":
        break;
    // more here
}
```

The debugger is your friend here.  You can set a breakpoint inside your method to inspect the object that is being passed in.

Comment: That's going to fail if `sender` is not a button.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: Yes, it certainly will, as well it should.  The OP says that he has a handler assigned to four buttons.  If the method is only supposed to handle events for a button then it should fail (and fail hard) if the sender is not a button.

Comment: That's one way to look at it, although it looks to me like a bug waiting for some unsuspecting maintenance programmer to run into. I would suggest first testing to see if `sender` is a button, and throwing an exception. Same result, but much easier to debug a message that says, `The sender parameter must be a Button.`

Comment: @Jim Mischel: Sure, you could do that.  In reality I have never run into a problem like that.  Event handler are typically wired to one or more of the same type of control.  If they are wired to controls of different types then obviously you should be casting to a specific type like this at all.  Either way, the exception would be obvious and the cause would be immediately evident.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you cast it to "Button" and use the "Name" property (of System.Windows.Forms.Control) ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name.aspx